# Action guard/middleware - How to check the conditions?

Tags: angular, rxjs, state, ngxs

I create large application and I need more control over the dispatch of actions.

I know that **I can check conditions in my components** and when the conditions are not sufficient I can cancel the dispatch-action call but it can be uncomfortable when more components have to check the same conditions.

### What should such a process look like?

I have idea but I'm not sure is a good solution:

1. `Component` check the conditions,
2. `Component` call `@Dispatch function` belongs to the `Facade` (large service)
3. `@Dispatch function` call `Guard` / `Middleware`,
4. `Guard` / `Middleware` **check the conditions again (if the conditions do not match throws an exception)**
5. `@Dispatch function` calls the action
6. ...

and if it's a good idea...

### How to implement such a guard?

Is it supposed to be in the form of a service or maybe arrow functions that accept `store` in the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

On the component level I suppose you can just implement your own filter and if that filter is in heavy reuse you can just set it up as a reusable pipeable operator

example rxjs filter

```
myCompFilter=pipe(filter(x=>x.....))
```

if you want normal filter it is just a plain function return true or false

```
filter=(x)=>x>0?
```

For action guard, you can just create a custom dispatch function by wrapping `store.dispatch()`

```
customDispatch=(action)=>if(x) store.dispatch()
```

so combine them together you'll get something like

```
doSomething.pipe(myCompFilter,tap(()=>customDispatch())
```

You can also make the customDispatcher and filter more customizable by return higher order function ( you can also call it partial function)